# How to stop firebug from breaking on error in scripts?

Tags: firefox, firebug

I have firebug 1.9.1 and I noticed that when there are pages that have scripting errors it goes to that line. It is like I have a breakpoint on that line but I don't.

How do I stop this. I don't mind on the firebug logo it has an error count but I find it so annoying that it is opening firebug up to show me lines it stopped at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the Firebug tabs, there is a "pause" button. The error console will thus break on errors, if that pause button is pressed. Just un-press that button.

Comment: Ya I saw that but I don't know if I should click it or not. When I click it, it starts flashing when I unclick it is just normal. However both give me the same result. For instance as a sample page(http://movies.msn.com/paralleluniverse/whos-who-in-the-avengers/photo-gallery/feature/) if I go here it stops on line 22 of some javascript file. This happens if I click the "pause" button then refresh. Then click on the "pause" button again and refresh.

Answer (score 8):

For everyone thinking "But the pause button in the script panel ***is*** un-pressed! It's not flashing! Pressing it turns it on and pressing again to turn it back off makes no difference!"...

...check **the *other* pause button in the Console panel**. *(If that's off too, check the third pause button under HTML, 'Break on mutate', or under Net, 'Break on XHR')*

It's a bit of a gotcha because if the Console pause button is pressed, errors take you to the script panel to debug *instead* of showing the error message in the console panel... So you have to check the status of the panel you're *not* taken to...

The console panel pause button is `Break on all errors`: whereas the Script panel button only breaks on the next error. It's easy to forget you turned on `Break on all errors`, then not notice it's still on because you're focusing on the panel you weren't expecting to be taken to.

Answer (score 1):

For me, Firebug was randomly breaking on each script being loaded - the solution was to go to the scripts tab -> Breakpoints tab (on right), and delete all of the breakpoints there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue for some time and kept just disabling the "Script" tab which is really annoying! I tried to click the pause button so it's flashing and refresh, same issue. Then, click so it's not flashing and refresh, same issue. I just now clicked the pause button (so it was blinking), then un-clicked it so it was not blinking, and then refreshed the page and it seems to have fixed it. The same page that was breaking on a script error is no longer breaking on the error.